# Why the SIGSEGV is triggered?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, gdb, embedded-linux, glibc

I have a multi-threaded program running on ARM platform. in one of the threads, I will call system() to run certain shell command.
Recently, I found that occasionally, the subprecess forked by system() will terminated with SIGSEGV.

strace shows the subprecess terminated with the following messege.

```
1423872694.771573 set_robust_list(0xb5a90070, 12) = 0
1423872694.773834 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
1423872694.774906 rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
1423872694.775973 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
1423872694.776986 execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "sync"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
1423872694.784928 brk(0)                = 0xea000
1423872694.786133 uname({sys="Linux", node="localhost", ...}) = 0
1423872694.787440 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1423872694.788602 --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xe} ---
1423872694.789370 +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

I got coredump file and analze it with gdb, the results are as followings.
It seems that segmentation fault can not occurred in this status. Would you like to tell why the SIGSEGV is triggered, or what I missed in finding the reason for SIGSEGV?

```
Core was generated by `sh -c sync'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x4d8f1008 in _dl_map_object (loader=0x4d912968, name=0xe1629 "libtinfo.so.5", type=<optimized out>, trace_mode=0, mode=0, nsid=0) at dl-load.c:2187
2187    dl-load.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x4d8f1008 in _dl_map_object (loader=0x4d912968, name=0xe1629 "libtinfo.so.5", type=<optimized out>, trace_mode=0, mode=0, nsid=0) at dl-load.c:2187
#1  0x4d8f647c in openaux (a=0xbe89a99c) at dl-deps.c:64
#2  0x4d8f83cc in _dl_catch_error (objname=0x0, errstring=0x4d912880 <data.11735>, mallocedp=0xbe89a9b8, operate=0xbe89a9b4, args=0xbe89a99c) at dl-error.c:178
#3  0x4d8f6708 in _dl_map_object_deps (map=0x4d912968, preloads=<optimized out>, npreloads=<optimized out>, trace_mode=0, open_mode=0) at dl-deps.c:257
#4  0x4d8ebbb4 in dl_main (phdr=<optimized out>, phnum=1301358928, user_entry=0x1, auxv=0x4d912050 <_rtld_global>) at rtld.c:1939
#5  0x4d8fede8 in _dl_sysdep_start (start_argptr=<optimized out>, dl_main=0x4d8fede8 <_dl_sysdep_start+572>) at ../elf/dl-sysdep.c:244
#6  0x4d8ea0b8 in _dl_start_final (arg=0xbe89bda0, info=<optimized out>) at rtld.c:431
#7  0x4d8ea3b8 in _dl_start (arg=0x0) at rtld.c:659
#8  0x4d8e8e30 in _start () from /opt/windriver/wrlinux/5.0-digital-spear320-newpuppy/sysroots/digital_spear320-wrs-linux-gnueabi/lib/ld-linux.so.3
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
(gdb) info registers 
r0             0x0  0
r1             0xe  14
r2             0x0  0
r3             0x4d911f30   1301356336
r4             0xe1629  923177
r5             0x0  0
r6             0x4d912968   1301358952
r7             0x4d912b00   1301359360
r8             0x1  1
r9             0x1  1
r10            0x0  0
r11            0x0  0
r12            0xbe89a72c   3196692268
sp             0xbe89a4e8   0xbe89a4e8
lr             0x2  2
pc             0x4d8f1008   0x4d8f1008 <_dl_map_object+672>
cpsr           0x20000010   536870928
(gdb) disassemble
   0x4d8f0fd8 <+624>:   ldr r1, [sp, #36]   ; 0x24
   0x4d8f0fdc <+628>:   add r3, pc, r12
   0x4d8f0fe0 <+632>:   add r12, sp, #572   ; 0x23c
   0x4d8f0fe4 <+636>:   str r12, [sp]
   0x4d8f0fe8 <+640>:   add r12, sp, #56    ; 0x38
   0x4d8f0fec <+644>:   stmib   sp, {r12, lr}
   0x4d8f0ff0 <+648>:   mov lr, #2
   0x4d8f0ff4 <+652>:   add r12, sp, #580   ; 0x244
   0x4d8f0ff8 <+656>:   add r3, r3, #24
   0x4d8f0ffc <+660>:   str lr, [sp, #12]
   0x4d8f1000 <+664>:   mov r0, r4
   0x4d8f1004 <+668>:   add lr, r12, #3
=> 0x4d8f1008 <+672>:   str lr, [sp, #16]
   0x4d8f100c <+676>:   bl  0x4d8ee9d0 <open_path>
   0x4d8f1010 <+680>:   cmn r0, #1
   0x4d8f1014 <+684>:   mov r1, r0
   0x4d8f1018 <+688>:   movne   r3, #0
   0x4d8f101c <+692>:   moveq   r3, #1
   0x4d8f1020 <+696>:   tst r3, r8
   0x4d8f1024 <+700>:   bne 0x4d8f119c <_dl_map_object+1076>
(gdb) x/64a 0xbe89a4e8 - 32 
0xbe89a4c8: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xe1629
0xbe89a4d8: 0x0 0x4d912968  0x0 0xe1629
0xbe89a4e8: 0xbe89a724  0xbe89a520  0x4d912968  0x2
0xbe89a4f8: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a508: 0x0 0xe 0x4d912968  0x0
0xbe89a518: 0x1 0x1 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a528: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a538: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a548: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a558: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a568: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a578: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a588: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a598: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a5a8: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0xbe89a5b8: 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
(gdb) info threads         
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    LWP 289           0x4d8f1008 in _dl_map_object (loader=0x4d912968, name=0xe1629 "libtinfo.so.5", type=<optimized out>, trace_mode=0, mode=0, nsid=0) at dl-load.c:2187
```

Comment: You get segmentation fault because there's an error in the code. If the code is yours then you can [debug it](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Otherwise you have to try to find a case where you can easily replicate the problem and report it to the author or maintainer of the program.

Comment: And don’t use `system()` call at all. It’s a 99.99% sign that code does something completely wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. The SIGSEGV occurred in ld-linux.so.3. What annoy me is I can not find anything that can trigger SIGSEGV in the coredump result. And this SIGSEGV only occurred occasionally.

Comment: Note that there's often a difference where the crash happens and where the actual root cause is located. Take for example the case of calling `strlen` with a null pointer, if it crashes then it happens in the `strlen` function but the problem itself isn't there. It might actually be several levels up in the calls stack.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps changing environment variables might have something to do with it.

Comment: @PSkocik, you are right, By backtrace, I can confirm that it is doing library-loading according to the environment variable of LD_LIBRARY_PATH. After I unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I can not reproduce this bug. But I can not find the causation of LD_LIBRARY_PATH with SIGSEGV. I am afraid that it is not the root cause.

Comment: @gzh It looks exactly like the cause of the segfault. The segmentation violation is happening inside the dynamic loader, which is controlled by environment variables such as LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @PSkocik, Usually, the SIGSEGV created is LD_LIBRARY_PATH is incompatible library version.  But there is only one set of library in my embedded system, incompatible library version can not occurred. And coredump shows SIGSEGV  occurred when trying to loading library files. not a link error.

Comment: Report the problem to the developers. Being neither the developers nor yours, we (Stack Overflow) cannot help you, as we don't have enough information about the problem.

Comment: @gzh Are you running a Chromebook?

Comment: @JL2210, No, just an ARM-based embedded system.

Answer (score 0):

> Would you like to tell why the SIGSEGV is triggered?

There is a bug in your version of GLIBC.

> After I unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I can not reproduce this bug.

The bug is somewhere in GLIBC handling of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

You didn't tell which version of GLIBC you are using, so it's hard to tell which bug this might be. Perhaps [this one](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10411)?

Comment: I noticed this bug. But my backtrace of coredump has different crash point with that bug. Furthermore, if I read the bugzilla correctly, This bug will incur segfault every time. In my case, the SIGSEGV only occurred occasionally.  By the way, the glibc version I am using is 2.15.